# Rational or Irrational number

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

we know that "$a$" is a Irrational number
.But "$a^2+a$" is Rational.
Can You find "$a$"? (more than one answer is available)

Comment: Any irrational number of form $\sqrt n - \frac{1}{2}$, where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: @vladz  no $sqrt(2) $ a bad example

Answer (score 12):

We have $a^2+a=r\in\Bbb Q$ if and only if
$$a=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4r}}{2}.$$
Any $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $1+4r$ is not a perfect square will do.

Answer (score 1):

Hint complete the square you get $(a+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$ so any number of the form $√n-\frac{1}{2}$ will give it as a cancels out with $-a$ making number rational.

Comment: though you need $n$ to not be a (rational) square to ensure $\sqrt{n}-\frac{1}{2}$ is irrational

Answer (score 0):

Consider  $x^2 + x = \dfrac pq$
for some relatively prime integers $p$ and $q$.

Hence $qx^2 + qx - p = 0$

So, for any relatively prime integers $p$ and $q$ such that $q^2 + 4pq$ is positive and not a perfect square,

$a \in \left\{ \dfrac{-q \pm \sqrt{q^2 + 4pq}}{2q} \right\}$

will have the property that $a$ is irrational and $a^2 + a = \dfrac pq$.